# Tomcat Java Servlet and JSON Reception issues

Tags: java, json, tomcat, servlets

I have multiple client machines that are processing and sending JSON (Post HTTP) to a central machine. The Central machine is running a Java Servlet and taking the HttpServletRequest variable (request) and doing a request.getReader() and pushing it to a string, which I later parse into a JSON Object.

Before I even get to parse into the JSON Object I sometimes get data corruption from the HttpServletRequest variable, where the JSON string has some previous data from another scanner, seems like the buffer wasn't cleared or something. 
I did confirm on the client machine that the data being sent out is correct.

1. Is there anything obvious on Java Servlets with DoPost that I might need to do? I wouldn't think there would be a need for synchronization.
2. Is there a way to see the full HTTP body within Tomcat without using a sniffer?

Comment: Why don't you post the code instead of explaining what is in it? A line of code is worth a thousand words in this case... By the way, the problem is most likely that you have something in the `static` fields in your Servlet that shouldn't be there. Likely a `Scanner` instance... (which is declared not threadsafe by the API doc)

Comment: Issue would be more clearer if you could paste your code snippet here

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909